# Android-Room error: package javax.annotation.processing does not exist

Tags: android, android-room

I have an android project with java and kotlin.
When i execute 'gradle app:assemble", i get the error output:

> error: package javax.annotation.processing does not exist import
> javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
>
> error: cannot find symbol @Generated("androidx.room.RoomProcessor")

I added 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2' but it's not working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dependencies for Room in my project are
`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"`, `"androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`.

i add `compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'`. it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I added this line of code in the file build.gradle(:app) in the part of dependencies and it works!

dependencies {
compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'

[image]

Source: https://github.com/pengrad/jdk9-deps

Comment: This works but why?

Answer (score 0):

it seem you didn't added annotation Processor dependencies
add this line in app Gradle file
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'

Answer (score 0):

Without adding any dependencies, I was able to get this working.

For me, I reverted (or stayed) at the last stable Gradle Plugin: `7.0.3` (there are *alpha* and *beta* versions available.

When trying to update to newer versions, I had this build issue.